# store dispatch actions is not a Constructor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am using ngrx for storing data. I am getting below error while calling action?

_global_store_actions_auth_actions__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.SetAuthTokenRequest is not a constructor

**myCompoment.ts**

```
import * as AuthActions from "../../global/store/actions/auth.actions";
import { Token } from "../../global/models";

const tk: Token = {
      access_token: "string",
    };
this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetAuthTokenRequest(tk));
```

**actions.ts**

```
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Token } from "../../models/token";

export declare enum AuthActionTypes {

SET_AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST = "[Core] SET_AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST",

export interface AuthenticationData {
  user: string;
  password: string;
}
export declare class SetAuthTokenRequest implements Action {
  payload: Token;
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.SET_AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST;
  constructor(payload: Token);
}
```

**reducer.ts**

```
import { Token } from "../../models";
import { AuthAction, AuthActionTypes } from "../actions";

export interface AuthState {
  token: Token;
  unverifiedUserToken: Token;
}

const initialValue: AuthState = {
  token: null,
  unverifiedUserToken: null
};

export function auth(state = initialValue, action: AuthAction): AuthState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.SET_AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
export declare class SetAuthTokenRequest implements Action {
  payload: Token;
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.SET_AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST;
  constructor(payload: Token);
}
```

You need to change like this

```
   export class SetAuthTokenRequest implements Action {
      public readonly type = AuthActionTypes.SET_AUTH_TOKEN_REQUEST;
      constructor(public readonly payload: Token);
    }
```

You can view my code [here](https://github.com/ngohungphuc/online-training/blob/master/Ref/ngrx-platform/example-app/app/auth/actions/auth.ts)

Comment: error - A parameter property is only allowed in a constructor. *** constructor(public readonly payload: Token);

Comment: private and public are only used in the class level, not function level (they're always private). Check your code again with my

Comment: Sorry, which .ts file to file check?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain can you also vote up my answer. Thank you